# Recursively apply function to list elements

Tags: r

Using the [rmatio](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmatio/index.html) package, I get nested lists similar to the following:

```
nestedlist <- list(
    a = list( a = list(1:10), b = list(35)),
    b = list(11:25)
)
```

Ideally, I want it to look like this (all lists with a single unnamed element replaced by the element):

```
nestedlist <- list(a = list(a=1:10, b=35), b = 11:25)
```

I tried the already tried the following:

```
unlist(nestedlist) # returns one vector with all elements

selective_unlist <- function(e)
    if(is.list(e) &&is.null(names(e))) unlist(e) else e

# only calls the function with each leaf, so nothing gets replaced
rapply(nestedlist, how='replace', selective_unlist)

# works, but only for 2 levels
lapply(nestedlist, selective_unlist)

# works, but using explicit recursion is slow for large datasets
recursive_selective_unlist <- function(e)
    if(is.list(e)) {
        if(is.null(names(e))) unlist(e)
        else lapply(e, recursive_selective_unlist)
    }   else e
```

Is there a better/faster way to simplify these nested lists or is the recursive function my best bet?

Comment: Specifying `recursive=FALSE` should do the trick when you only have one degree of nesting (as in your example object) - `unlist(nestedlist,recursive=F)`.

Comment: @nrussell Thank you for the suggestion, but some files have up to 8 levels

Comment: @Frank I forgot to update it in the edit, it's now corrected

Comment: Maybe relevant convo from 2002: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2002-June/022349.html The writer says he found a solution to "apply a function only on terminal nodes" but neglected to provide it, instead opting for a dead link and "email me".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following @Pafnucy's idea, I'd use

```
ff <- function(x) if (is.list(x[[1]])) lapply(x,ff) else unlist(x)
```

which does

```
ff(nestedlist)
# $a
# $a$a
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
# 
# $a$b
# [1] 35
# 
# 
# $b
#  [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
# check result:
identical(list(a = list(a=1:10, b=35), b = 11:25),ff(nestedlist))
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: This works, but with a small dataset (4 levels, 50 elements) it's about 30% slower than explicit recursion.

Comment: still, `lapply(f(nl3), as.vector)` is needed for this function to work on nl2 and nl3, as it produces matrices here and there

Comment: @Pafnucy I've just switched from `sapply` to `lapply` and so there shouldn't be any matrices now.

Comment: @tstenner If the `rmatio` package is giving you large objects in this format, maybe there is a reason, and you should learn how to work with them instead of modifying them in this way. I've never worked with a list in R that is so large that operations on it are time consuming.

Answer (score 2):

Handling arbitrary depth of nesting:

```
f <- function(x) {
    if (is.list(x)) unname(c(sapply(unlist(x), f))) else x
}

# sample data
nl2 <- list(a = list(a = list(1:5), b = list(1:5)))
nl3 <- list(p = nl2, q = c(9,9,9))
```

**Intermediate output:**

```
> f(nl2)
 [1] 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5
> f(nl3)
 [1] 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 9 9 9
```

Adding last step, as `f` goes too deep and we want list with depth 1

```
unstackList <- function(x) lapply(x, f)
unstackList(nl3)
```

**Output:**

```
$p
 [1] 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5

$q
[1] 9 9 9
```

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to `unname(unlist(x))`?

Comment: @Frank it is almost what OP wants, without final step. Solution is `lapply(nestedlist, f)`, with `f` defined as above. I'll add that to solution

Comment: It's still not quite OP's output. Try `identical` with `unstackList(nestedlist)` against this result mentioned in the OP: `list(a = list(a=1:10, b=35), b = 11:25)`

Comment: The resulting list should be nested, but without the unneeded lists with no name (and a single element).

Comment: @tstenner Well, it occured to me I'm completely off-topic with above answer. The real goal is lowering nesting depth for lists with 1 numeric element. How about list(1:10, a = 4:8), should we end up with list(a=4:8)?

Comment: @Pafnucy Good question. I hadn't thought about it, as the lists I handle have either one unnamed element or multiple named elements.